# Submit a Radio Buttom and pass parameter in Rails to link or buttom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I make a loop to show my options and need make a link or buttom to pass the value of my radio buttom to my link or buttom but i dont know how i get this value, please someone can help, my loop whit my journals is:

```
<div id="add_post">
<h1>Escolha o Jornal que deseja adicionar:</h1>
 <ul>
<% current_user.journals.each do |journal| %>
        <li><%= radio_button_tag 'journal',journal.id %><%= journal.name %></li>
<%end%>
 </ul>
<%= link_to "Adicionar",add_post_complete_journal_path(HEREEE),:remote=>true %>
</div>
```

Where say HEREEE is where i want appear the options choised, please help me i thanks very very mutch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JS/Jquery to achieve the same. Just give a name to all radio buttons like "myradiobutton". Then get the value of selected radio button using Jquery and pass it via an AJAX call.

Something like:

```
var selected_value = $("input[name='myradiobutton']:checked").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "<%= add_post_complete_journal_path %>",
    data: {selected_val:selected_value},
    success: function(data){
      // Do something after success
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Very thanks, i modified some parts but this works for me very very thanks man, write the code here to help others people if have same situation:

```
<%= submit_tag "Adicionar",:class => "enviar" %>


<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#add_post .enviar").click(function(){

    var selected_value = $("#add_post input[type='radio']:checked").val();

    if(!selected_value) {
        alert("Selecione algum jornal para adicionar !");
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "<%= add_post_complete_journal_path %>",
        data: {selected_val:selected_value},
        success: function(data){
            $.fancybox("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'journals/add_post_complete')%>",
              {
                openEffect: "fade",
                closeEffect: "fade",
                autoSize: true,
                minWidth: 480,
                scrolling: 'auto',
              });
        }
    });

    });

});
    </script>
```